# The specified JDK Version is "2724.0.0.0.0", while the maximum is "500.0.0.0.0"

Tags: java, netbeans-platform

While installing the Netbeans IDE latest version, i encountered the error

"The specified JDK Version is "2724.0.0.0.0", while the maximum is "500.0.0.0.0" "

Not sure on what is causing this issue. Class Path, Java Home all have been set correctly. Even the jdk path is given correctly in the Netbeans

[image: Error]

Kindly help me in the same.

Answer (score 7):

NetBeans 12.5 runs using a JRE which should be either version 8, 11 or 17.0.1 or higher (NOT JDK 17). To run it, install JDK 17.0.1 (Recommended because it's the latest LTS)

Update (Oct 13, 2021): I tried JDK 16.0.2 and it also works. JDK 17 still doesn't work.

Update 2 (Oct 22, 2021): I realised that JDK 17.0.1 had come out, so I tried it with NetBeans 12.5 and it works now. Maybe JDK 17 was a bit bugged in terms of version numbers. Anyways, it officially works with JDK 17.0.1

Comment: I have tried with JDK 11. it worked for me

Comment: Yeah I also tried with jdk17.0.0 and it didn't work, but
 when I installed 17.0.1(today), it worked like a charm. So i guess there was a minor bug in jdk17.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. Go to https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html
and dwnload the zip file. then extract it and go to bin folder and open netbeans.exe(netbeans64.exe if 64 bit).

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that your answer is also correct. But here, the OP wants to know why JDK 17 was not working with Netbeans 12.5, so consider adding an explanation here.

Comment: @JustInCoding Ok Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and in my case, changing the JDK to OpenJDK resolved the problem. You can download OpenJDK from Microsoft's official website at https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk.

After downloading, you can findit in the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-17.x.x.x" directory.