# Can't install Netbeans 12.6 with jdk.17

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have been facing this problem for a while and it started getting frustrating, as you see in the picture [image] it says "the specific jdk folder contains  version 2727.0.0.0.0" while maximum is "500.0.0.0.0" and I don't get it I installed the latest NetBeans IDE and the latest jdk which is jdk.17 and I get this problem, can anyone help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69309296/the-specified-jdk-version-is-2724-0-0-0-0-while-the-maximum-is-500-0-0-0-0#comment123818752_69309564

Comment: @xerx593 yes it did thank you very much